# Admob android : Rewarded video not showing sometimes

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I want to implement rewarded video on my android application, the first time i click to show video, is works just fine, but after that the second or the third time i click to show it again, it doesn't work, and throws on the log :

```
W/MessageQueue: Handler (com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer2.upstream.u) {1e5487c} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer2.upstream.u) {1e5487c} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                                         at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(Handler.java:534)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessage(Handler.java:519)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer2.upstream.u.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:212)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)


Could not show rewarded video ad from adapter.
                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bq ip.a' on a null object reference
                                                              at com.google.ads.mediation.a.g(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:17227)
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.u.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:436)
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:1314)
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.client.e.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:65)
                                                              at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznu$zza$zza.show(Unknown Source)
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoc.show(Unknown Source)
                                                              at com.reperfection.monopoly.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22546)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Could not call showVideo.
                                                          android.os.RemoteException
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.u.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:439)
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:1314)
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.client.e.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:65)
                                                              at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznu$zza$zza.show(Unknown Source)
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoc.show(Unknown Source)
                                                              at com.reperfection.monopoly.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22546)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {

TextView counterTV;
ImageView clickerBoard;
int counter;
int step = 1;
RelativeLayout parentRl;
LinearLayout ln1;
LinearLayout ln2;
private RewardedVideoAd mAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    counterTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
    parentRl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentRl);
    clickerBoard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.clickerBoard);
    ln1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ln1);
    ln2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ln2);

    // Init rewarded video
    mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
    loadRewardedVideoAd();

    ln1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mAd.isLoaded()) {
                mAd.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    mAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
            reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Reward the user.
}

// The following listener methods are optional.
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mAd.resume(this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mAd.pause(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mAd.destroy(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}}
```

Can you help to figure out what is wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION**

I faced the same issue and looking to the [official example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/kotlin/admob/RewardedVideoExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/rewardedvideoexample/MainActivity.kt) I found that they are not calling

```
RewardedVideoAd.destroy(Context)
```

Although they tell to call it in their [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video). So after **removing** it, it worked.

Comment: It realy looks like solution!

Comment: So bizarre. Would this not leak stuff?

Answer (score 1):

I'm placing an admob video, which is executed when you enter the activity, I had the same problem when entering the activity for the second time. In my case I put an executable loop to start the video when it is already loaded.

```
if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
    }else{
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }
```

This is part of all my code

```
private boolean started = false;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private void initializeAdMob() {
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}

private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(getString(R.string.id_block_activity), new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}

private void showRewardedVideoAd() {
    if (BaseInteractor.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
        showProgressBar(true);
        start();
    }
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        }else{
            loadRewardedVideoAd();
        }
        if (started) {
            start();
        }
    }
};

public void stop() {
    started = false;
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

public void start() {
    started = true;
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
}
```

finally I stop the runnable in

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    showProgressBar(false);
    stop();
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [manual](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAdListener) it seems you have to reload your video:
override this method

```
onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
loadRewardedVideoAd();
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what i do : @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you requested to get an ad from admob, when you have already got another admob video request for getting an ad from admob and the 1st request you made returns respond with an ad and you decided to show() ad, you are getting **Could not show rewarded video ad from adapter**. error.

I thought that this is about singleton somehow. The second request you made, breaks something in first request. This confuses people because you are allowed to create multiple instance of `com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener()` . In my case we have to block second request to admob if you have already waiting response from first one.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly the same issue and after couple of days of investigation I found the solution.

You have to be really careful of your `RewardedVideoAd` lifecycle.
In my case, I tied my activity lifecycle to this object. But I understood that calling `onResume()` to the `RewardedVideoAd` object will kind of "re-init" it, so even if you loaded an ad before, you will need to reload one.

And as you might have found in other threads, do not try to load ads simultaneously, even though the SDK allows it. Be sure in your flow that you will load an ad **only** if no ad is pre-loaded, or if you just called `onResume()` to your `RewardedVideoAd` object.

Do not hesitate to log your `RewardedVideoAd` callback methods to help you understand and optimize your ad loading flow.

Answer (score 0):

According to the google docs [(link)](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-ads#using_rewardedadcallback_to_preload_the_next_rewarded_ad) for the new Rewarded Video Ads.

> RewardedAd is a one-time-use object. This means that once a rewarded ad is shown, the object can't be used to load another ad. To request another rewarded ad, you'll need to create a new RewardedAd object.

So if you need the second ad you need to dispose the existing rewardedAd object and create a new object.
you may do it like:

```
rewardedAd=null;
rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");
```